# Parse Html tag using JavaRegex or Jsoup

Tags: java, apache-poi, jsoup

I need to parse the text of unordered list item. My source is like below :

```
<ul>
<li><em><strong><span style="color:#FFFFF">Bolded and Colored Text</span></strong>      </em></li>
 <li>No Styling...Just a Text</li>
 <li><u><b>Bolded </b> and <i>Italic </i> and Underlined Text</u></li>
  <li><u>Underline Started and <span style="color:#FFFFF>Only Colored Text</span> Underline Ended</u></li>
```

Now I need to get the each and every text inside the tag:

```
tag, subtag text
```

Comment: Definetily use Jsoup. But is not clear for me, what output do you exactly want? Just write it down, for that example

Answer (score 1):

Jsoup would be a good option. You could parse it like

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;

public class JsoupParser {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String html = "<ul>"
                + "<li><em><strong><span style=\"color: #FFFFF\">Bolded and Colored Text</span></strong> </em></li>"
                + "<li>No Styling...Just a Text</li>"
                + "<li><u><b>Bolded </b> and <i>Italic </i> and Underlined Text</u></li>"
                + "<li><u>Underline Started and <span style=\"color: #FFFFF\">Only Colored Text</span> Underline Ended</u></li>"
                + "</ul>";

        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
        for(Element elem : doc.select("*")){
            System.out.println("Tag Name : " + elem.tagName());
            System.out.println("Value : " + elem.text());
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Syam.. thanks. yeah almost i got the info to what am looking for.

Comment: My actual requirement is to show the html formatted text inside the excel. For example, if am getting the html from backend is  <b>Iam bold</b> and <i>I am the <u>also underline</u> italic</i>. I need to show the format as it is in excel based on the tags. text with <b> is to shown bold inside the excel and text with <i> is to show italic inside the excel. How can i do that am using XssfRichTextString. But not getting idea how to applyFont to richstring that based on the parsing of tags

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16610881/html-formatted-cell-value-from-excel-using-apache-poi. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Syam.. I was looking the opposite for that.. I have to set or applyfont based on the parsing of the html tags came from backend data.  Like after parsing through jsoup, if the tagname is <u> then i need to apply the tag's text to underline inside excel through xssfrichstring() method